# PDO Prepared Statements: Replacing the value of a column

Tags: php, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

How do you use prepared statements and bound parameters to replace a value in a column? For example,

```
$stmt = "UPDATE users SET name = :name
    WHERE name = :name";

$stmt->bindParam(:name, $oldName);
$stmt->bindParam(:name, $newName);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Doh! Of course that' the solution..my brain doesn't work at this hour apparently. Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use same named bind parameters within `prepare` statement your parameters name must be unique as

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("UPDATE users SET name = :newName
    WHERE name = :oldName");

$stmt->bindParam(':oldName', $oldName);
$stmt->bindParam(':newName', $newName);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use different placeholder:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE users SET name = :newname
    WHERE name = :oldname")
$stmt->bindParam(':oldname', $oldName);
$stmt->bindParam(':newname', $newName);
$stmt->execute();
```